# How to get the loop to enumarate in order the objects in the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, enumerate

So its a simple question really, i was trying out some code to have a better understanding about how for loops with multiple variables work in python so i wrote this:

```
list={18,23,45,67,230}

for i, j in enumerate(list):
    print("i: ", i, " j: ", j)
```

Its my understanding that the loop should print in order the contents of the list, however i get the following output

```
i:  0  j:  18
i:  1  j:  67
i:  2  j:  230
i:  3  j:  23
i:  4  j:  45
```

Can anyone be so kind to explain to me as why its not printed in order?. I havent found an answer to this in any of my "go to" places for questions like this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: The problem is that you defined your list with curly brackets `{}` which creates a set. Use square brackets `[]` to create an ordered list. Also, don't use `list` as the name of a variable is shadows the `list` type that is built in to Python.

Comment: Your question is really on - the data structure is not `list` is a `set`.   as you show here - `{ ..... }`  If you change to `[.....numbers]` you will get it.

Comment: Another side note - please avoid using the built-in `list` as the variable name.

Comment: @Pankaj - That doesn’t matter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variable is not a `list` but a `set` (try printing `type(list)`). For this reason, given that a set imposes no order to its values, you'll consequently get such output.

In order to define a list you should use squared brackets:

```
lst = [18,23,45,67,230]

for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    print("i: ", i, " j: ", j)
```

Output:

```
i:  0  j:  18
i:  1  j:  23
i:  2  j:  45
i:  3  j:  67
i:  4  j:  230
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `list={18,23,45,67,230}`
to

```
list=[18,23,45,67,230]
```